# Problem displaying multiple images in a view in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

I have a problem displaying multiple images in view. I have a group of product images but am unable to display them in view. Kindly assist.

```
public function getProductImages(){
    $products = Products::all();
    $arrayOfImages = [];
    foreach($products as $product){
        $arrayOfImages[$product->id] = $product->images()->get();
    }
    return view('products', ['productImages' => $product]);
}
```

My view looks like this://here is where the problem is

```
 @foreach($images as $image)
    <div class="carousel-item {{ $loop->first ? 'active' : '' }}">
      <img class="d-block w-100" src="/images2/{{$image->filename}}"/>
    </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: try with [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) and 2 foreach loop if you have multiple images for single product. 1 for loop for product and inside of that 1 for images.

Comment: @Bhaumik, thanks for single products I am able to display using a link like http://localhost:8000/products/6 but it only displays only images for that product. What I want is now all the images for all product in the same page

Comment: I think your foreach should be "@foreach($productImages as $image)"

Comment: @ThiagoBrauer thanks but now i get an error Trying to get property 'filename' of non-object

Comment: check if $image is either an object or an array